# How to Enable or Disable Text Box in GridView using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to enable/disable a textbox inside gridview.  I have case statement and in my case statement when `Case = 1` then I want to disable a texbox called `txtType` in my gridview. Here is my code:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select * from my table ", con);
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RSP_SET_SK", (RSP_SET_SK));
da.Fill(dtTable);

GridView1.DataSource = dtTable.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();

DataRow dtTable_row = dtTable.Rows[0];

if (dtTable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DDL_TYPE.SelectedValue = dtTable_row.Field<string>("TYPE").ToString();
    ddlPr.SelectedValue = dtTable_row.Field<Int32>("ID").ToString();
}

DataRow row1 = dtTable.Rows[0];
int temp = Convert.ToInt32(row1["STATUS"]);

switch (temp)
{
   case 1:
     lblStatus.Text = temp + " - Initial Test.";

   break;
}
```

Comment: textbox.Enabled = false; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: it is inside gridview

Comment: A textbox is a TextBox you have go get it, google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is in a gridview, you will need to use this..

```
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
string type = ((TextBox).gvr.FindControl("txtType"));
```

Then to disable or enable you can use..

```
type.Enabled = true;
```

I hope that gives you the general idea how to do it.

Edit: You might need to use a foreach loop.

```
foreach(GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    string type = ((TextBox).gvr.FindControl("txtType"));
    type.Enabled = true/false;
}
```

This should do it I would imagine. I do use this foreach pretty often in one of my applications.

Edit 2:

I just realized I put a period where it should not. My bad. So it should be this.

```
string type = ((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtType"));
```

or

```
TextBox type = ((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtType"));
```

or you can just enable it straight up like this..

```
((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("txtType")).Enabled = true/false;
```

Comment: it says the name Sender does not exist in the current context.  thnx

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I used a foreach loop.

Comment: you could also just put it in the RowUpdating event of the gridview.

Comment: it does not like adding this: ((TextBox) in front of gvr

Comment: This line does not make any sense: 'string type = ((TextBox).gvr.FindControl("txtType"));`

Comment: I think it should be TextBox not string.

Comment: @moe I made some edits to my answer. I added an extra period that shouldn't be there. Long day yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in `RowDataBound` event. First, make sure you set `OnRowDataBound` property in the aspx code like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

Then add the following in code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView data = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        TextBox txtType = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtType");
        int status = Convert.ToInt32(data["STATUS"]);
        if (status == 1)
        {
            txtType.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the STATUS on `int status = Convert.ToInt32(data["STATUS"]);` means? is that a field on a table or ID of textbox or what

Comment: It's a field name of the table based on the question above. If your table has a different field name, then you'll need to change `data["STATUS"]` to `data["yourfieldname"]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in **RowDataBound Event**. Below link has sample code which can help you.

[Reference](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource17-RowDatabound-event-tips-and-tricks-in-Gridview-control.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
 a TextBox into a GridView

<asp:GridView ID="mygrid" runat="server">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField meta:resourcekey="TemplateFieldResource4">
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="mytextBoxID" runat="server" Text="0,00" Enabled="false" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <HeaderStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
   <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void any_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gvData.Rows)
       ((TextBox)gvr.FindControl("mytextBoxID")).Enabled = true;
 }
```